# Export multiple animations to .json

Tags: animation, export, three.js

I'm trying to export cube to .json which has multiple actions (bouncing, scaling...).
But every time in json file I get just one animation that was actually selected, which name in json is "default".
I saw other projects with rigging, which had different actions as well (idle, walk, run...) and it was expotred and named by the name of action (not "default ")
Is it possible to expot my model the same way? Thanks.

Blender v. 2.79 
JSON exporter 1.5.0

[image]

[image: There are some actions, which I want to export to separate animations]

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to try using [this Blender exporter](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf), exporting to glTF, and loading into three.js with [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader). Many other workflows have trouble handling multiple animations.